# How to print corresponding lines from multiple files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a program which prints 3 bits of information, forename, surname and date of birth. These are all stored in separate text files. Each line of one text file goes with the same line number of the other text files.
I want to print the information like this:

```
John Smith 02/01/1980
```

My code does this but is very long, is there a way to shorten my code and still print the information the way i want. The code below prints the information of 10 people.

```
def reportone():
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[1-1], end='')
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[2-1], end='')
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[3-1], end='')
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[4-1], end='')
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[5-1], end='')
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[6-1], end='')
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[7-1], end='')
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[8-1], end='')
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[9-1], end='')
    print()
    for file in ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]:
        with open(file) as f:
            print(f.readlines()[10-1], end='')
reportone()
```

Answer (score 2):

File objects are *iterators*, so you could use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to aggregate the corresponding lines from all the files, e.g.

```
with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2, open("file3.txt") as f3:
    for lines in zip(f1, f2, f3):
        print(*map(str.strip, lines))
```

Comment: Thanks this works however it indents two of the three pieces of data, the date of birth and surname.

Comment: You may want to use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to get rid of whitespace.

Comment: what line would i put  str.strip()

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
titles = ["Forename", "Surname", "Date of birth"]

data = [open("{}.txt".format(i)).readlines() for i in titles]

for forename, surname, dob in zip(*data):
     print(forename, surname, dob)
```

Comment: Does this leave the file open after reading the lines? Or does it implicitly get closed?

Comment: @Keatinge Python automatically closes any file that has been opened for reading.